# How should this Python function be called

Tags: python, function, scripting, modularity

I am having a trouble correctly referencing a recently added fpath() function. The code takes an argument from the commandline in the form of a file, wildcard or folder for use in the last code block.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os, sys, glob
from optparse import OptionParser

#logic to determine if argument is a file, folder or wildcard
def fpath(arguments):
    files = []
    for arg in arguments:
        if '*' in arg or '?' in arg:
            # contains a wildcard character
            all_files.extend(glob.glob(arg))
        elif os.path.isdir(arg):
            # is a dictionary
            all_files.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(arg, '*')))
        elif os.path.exists(arg):
            # is a file
            all_files.append(arg)
        else:
            # invalid?
            print '%s invalid' % arg
    return files

def main():

# List files in directory and upload them
    all_files = ''
    all_files = fpath(filename)
    for filename in all_files:
        #skip all directory entries which are not a file
        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
              continue
        k.set_contents_from_filename(filename, cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you've added to this script, and what was previously existing (presumably you started with a working program). Could you add some comments or something?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: I added a traceback from the script after adding your recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code pattern has some issues:

```
all_files = ''
def fpath(arguments):
    all_files = []
    # modify all_files
    return all_files
```

It looks like you want to pass back the content of `all_files` to the caller. There are two general ways to do this, with a global variable and with a return value:

### Global variable

To make this work with global variables, you need to tell Python that you're going to modify a global variable from within a function using the `global` statement:

```
all_files = ''
def fpath(arguments):
    global all_files
    all_files = []
    # modify all_files
```

In this case, you also don't need the `return` since the result is available to the caller in the global variable.

### Return value

A better way is probably to have the function return `all_files`:

```
def fpath(arguments):
    files = []
    # modify files
    return files

all_files = fpath(filename)
```

This eliminates the use of a global variable, which is generally considered poor practice and is prone to errors and confusion. I have also changed the name of the array inside the `fpath` function to just `files`, to clarify that `files` and `all_files` really are different variables. They *can* have the same name, but they would still be two different variables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have edited the original question with the suggestions you have made. There is a traceback stating **local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment**.

Comment: Yes, you're trying to pass `filename` to `fpath(filename)` before `filename` has any value at all. In Python, you need to give a variable some value before trying to use it.